# Is CloudFront still applicable if granular access change often?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a use case where I store images in S3. I need to make users of my web app access to the image globally, so I'm planning to use CloudFront for the CDN. However, I need to limit user access to individual images. For example, `user A` has access to `image 1`, and `user B` has access to `image 2`.

The access permission can change for user at any time. Because of this I'm thinking of having a lambda to serve the image so that I can control the granular access within the lambda. So from the frontend, the access path is `user --> CloudFront --> lambda --> S3` instead of `user --> CloudFront --> S3`

Will CloudFront still work with this approach? My impression is that CloudFront won't know if access to a file has been removed, and so it will still serve the image from its cache.

Are there any better ways to handle this use case?

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for [signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html)

Comment: @AnonCoward thanks for the suggestion! I think signed long-term URL would work, although it still requires the frontend to make one additional API call to get the signed URL.